# Invalid Ojbect Name msaccess 97

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am recieveing an invalid object name when calling the following code via .net but access its fine its been working fine since I had to do a reinstall of ms office 97 but I dunno how to fix it im excuting this. The same query imports fine in msaccess

```
        retVal = "INSERT INTO SkechersPricat select * FROM " & _
         "[Text;Database=" & sPathtoTextFile & ";HDR=YES].[" & sfileName & "]"
```

which is producing the following

```
 INSERT INTO SkechersPricat select * FROM [Text;Database=C:\Three_Software\Incoming\Skechers;HDR=YES].[Pricat.edi.csv]

 Invalid object name 'Text;Database=C:\Three_Software\Incoming\Skechers;HDR=YES.Pricat.edi.csv'.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the VB.NET code that actually uses the `retVal` variable to run the query.

Comment: Check out this link and see if it helps.  Not sure you've provided sufficient data for us to actually answer here.
http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=294800